# Tailwind Custom Colors Not recompiled with Twin.macro and styled component

Tags: babeljs, tailwind-css, styled-components

I'm trying to use a custom color, but I got a problem when I change the color on the tailwind config, Twin.macro does not recompile the style,

p.s: it's worked fine when I use it with `className`

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  important: true,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // primary: '#00bcd4',
        primary: '#fde047',
      },
    },
  }
}
```

```
// babel-plugin-macros.config.js
module.exports = {
  twin: {
    preset: 'styled-components',
    autoCssProp: false,
  },
}
```

```
// .babelrc.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [['next/babel', { 'preset-react': { runtime: 'automatic' } }]],
  plugins: ['babel-plugin-macros', 'babel-plugin-styled-components'],
}
```

Example of usage

```
<div className="text-primary">Hello </div> // Color change
<div tw="text-primary">#Dégage_Akhannouch</div> // Color does not change
```